# Concatenate Panels with different major indexes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have measurement sets that are stored in a dataframe like the following:

```
time cname c1 c2 c3
  1         0  1  2
  2         3  4  5
  3         6  7  8
  4         9 10 11
```

where each col is a different measured signal. Each of the sets is measured at a certain parameter value (say temperature), but also the time index is different for each set (although it has the same length.

The problem of multi-index dataframes is then that you need to set so many time levels as number of sets you have, so it becomes very dirty. Therefore I have started using Panels, so that each DataFrame is "contained" in one item.

The question now is how to concatenate those dataframes maintaining the different time-indexes (major_indexes in this case). In other words I have this:

```
pn1 = pd.Panel(randn(1,3,3), items=['a'], major_axis=[1,2,3], minor_axis=['c1','c2','c3'])
pn2 = pd.Panel(randn(1,3,3), items=['d'], major_axis=[3,4,5], minor_axis=['c1','c2','c3'])
pn = pd.concat([pn1,pn2], axis=0)

pn['a']
Out[24]: 
         c1        c2        c3
1  1.110590 -0.937210  0.220479
2  0.583298 -0.255046  2.068040
3 -1.231154 -1.338226  1.308702
4       NaN       NaN       NaN
5       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

But I want each item to conserve its original major_index. How can I proceed? Is there a better way to organize such data with Dataframes?

Comment: by definition the concatenation will union the other non-concat axis. That is the point of a Panel, that you have uniform indicies. If you don't want/need this. A dict of frames is usually pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I was suspecting this. I would prefer to avoid the use of dicts since the keys cannot be ordered and it gets messy when you want to plot each set in temperature order for instance, or if you need to get the average of repeated sets. But I will look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

this seems a natural problem to use a multi-level index (index is what you have as items/major_axis) and columns as minor_axis. The levels don't have to be fully populated.

```
In [16]: df1 = pn1.transpose('minor_axis','items','major_axis').to_frame()

In [17]: df2 = pn2.transpose('minor_axis','items','major_axis').to_frame()

In [18]: concat([df1,df2])
Out[18]: 
                   c1        c2        c3
major minor                              
a     1     -1.202766 -0.502679  1.915304
      2      0.097658  0.604051 -0.497243
      3     -1.285027 -1.200143  0.087209
d     3     -0.231444  1.518543  2.139600
      4     -1.336436 -0.299769 -0.600134
      5     -1.193389  1.449733 -0.857263
```

Comment: Beat me to it. It just took me ages to recreate the dataframes, `.to_frame()` is a nice thing I learned out of this - I should really work with panels more often.

Comment: Hmm... That would somehow make the job. How would you take the average over two repeated 'a' (major) for instance?

Comment: ``df.groupby(level='major').mean()`` (but its not clearn what you mean by repeated 'a', their are currently 3 repeats of 'a' here, namely 1,2,3).

Comment: Here 1,2,3 would be the time and 'a' the temperature at which measurement was made. Let's say I have another set 'a' at the same temperature with also 1,2,3 as time values. I'd need to average those sets, so that only one 'a' major with 1,2,3 minors exist with the average values

Comment: if you have multiple 'a's then you should have another level

Comment: I see.. That's why I think dataframes are not enough for this.

Comment: not a problem to have another level. see sa sample here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers

Comment: Yes but how do you set this other level? You need to group all the repeated values in the major index and assign a label to each, then set those as a new level..

Comment: why don't you ask a new question showing specifically what you are looking